# Resolución pantalla

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, vb, diseño

Estoy programando aplicaciones de escritorio para Windows con Visual Studio.

El problema que tengo es que yo programo con un portátil de 15'' con resolución de 1920x1080 y, las aplicaciones son para pantallas de diferentes pulgadas y diferentes resoluciones.

Entonces la parte visual en mi ordenador se ve bien, pero luego cuando paso el programa a las otras pantallas ya no se ven bien, y tengo que descargar el IDE en esas pantallas para modificar cada tamaño de cada elemento.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo responsive o de ajustar el tamaño de alguna forma?

Gracias.

Comment: No se ven bien a que t refieres, a que los controles se descolocan de sitio o que se agrandan automaticamente y se salen de la pantalla o se sobreponen unos a otros?

Comment: Para que los controles se vayan colocando a su sitio con diferentes resoluciones tienes que jugar con los Anchor de cada control o panel de los formularios, de esta manera se van colocando en su sitio automáticamente, aunque muchas veces no como esperabas, para eso probablemente tendras que dibujar tu mismo el formulario por codigo

Comment: Exacto, se agrandan o disminuyen y, se sobreponen algunos también. Vale, imaginaba que debía ser con los Anchor...Por código lo veo algo engorroso ya que muchas veces hay cambios y por lo tanto reestructuración de el diseño.
Y hay alguna forma de visualizar el diseño del formulario según una resolución que se le asigne? Utilizo Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Si hablamos de windows forms, intenta jugar con [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) aunque el control que vas a tener va sersiempre limitado dado que es una teconologia bastante obsoleta. Yo trataría de migrar a WPF que da mucho mas control en aplicaciones de escritorio

Comment: Con TableLayoutPanel he probado pero solo me lo hace medianamente bien si hay pocos elementos dentro de cada cuadro. Perdona mi desconocimiento, WPF es con C# verdad? WPF una vez probe a hacer un mini proyecto y no encontre el control ReportViewer, que es algo necesario para mi aplicación.

Comment: Wpf puedes usarlo con vb.net tambien. Y se puede usar ReportViewer , aunque yo solo lo uso por detras para generar informes, no les muestro en pantalla. Pero creo que recordar que tambien es posible.

Comment: Estas usando una tecnologia de hace mas de 20 años, en monitores con resoluciones varias. Si se puede ajustar, y vas a tener que tener cuidado con los tamaños minimos y maximos, pero te diria que tenes que ir pensando en migrar a algo mucho mas moderno, salvo que sea un programa viejo.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de compilar, asegurate que el form no este con escalado, si no mas bien la ventana al 100% y compilas.  De esa forma te aseguras que el binario tenga la resolución que ves tú en pantalla.  A mi me ocurre eso con vs2017

Comment: Donde puedo ver si esta con escalado?

Comment: Al abrir el formualrio puede aparecer un mensaje, en la parte superior, que indica "El escalador de la pantalla principal esta establecido en el 150%  Reiniciar Visual Studio con escalado del 100%"